# Trouble with Fortran 77 compiler option to change continuation line limit

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-options

I'm working on a project trying to compile old code on a new machine. As a background, the code compiles on 32 bit Linux machines, and the company wants it to work on a 64 bit machine. It appears that the compiler we're using (Absoft f77:

```
f77 -v
Absoft 64-bit Pro Fortran 11.5.3
ERROR: No input files.
```

) is more strict with some of the files. Specifically, it doesn't like the number of continuation lines in several files.

> More than 99 continuation lines in fixed source form is not allowed.

The company has worked around this by tediously changing the file format to try to fit in the 99 line limitation. Part of my overall responsibility is to get the program running on the new machine. I can try squishing many of the problem files down, but many people are annoyed with that approach, since even though it 'works', it becomes inconvenient for other reasons(organization of different groups of variables, names, comparing versions of the files , etc.)

I'm new at the company, and new to Fortran. I have researched a bunch about it, but I'm still missing some key concepts.

In my research, I think I found a solution, though I'm having trouble implementing it. From oracle:

> **Continuation Lines** The default maximum number of continuation lines is 99 @ (1 initial and 99 continuation). To change this number of lines, use the -Nln option. @
> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6l/index.html

I apologize if the text didn't copy over correctly. what I'm thinking is that if I use the '-N1' option in my makefile, it should let me specify a number of lines. So far, I haven't had success; I'm probably using it incorrectly.

```
f77 -N1 100 $(other flags...)
```

Isn't that the compiler? From the Oracle suggestion, I added the '-N1 100' bit, trying different numbers, but any time I try it, it still says 99 continuation lines is the limit.  I think I'm missing something. My guess is that I'm completely wrong about the option I'm passing in.

Per comments, I think the option is `-Nlxx`, but that option still isn't working. I think I found something that says the 99 line limit is strict in the reference guide, even though other Absoft f77 manuals say it can handle unlimited lines.

Comment: Looking at the linked site, "To change this number of lines, use the -Nl n option." , isn't the option `-Nl 100` rather than `-N1 100`? (i.e., "el" rather than "one"?)

Comment: hmm... If that is it I must be using it incorrectly still. I have replaced all of my  "f77 -N1 100" calls with "f77 -Nl 100", but still no luck... I am putting a space in between. Should I be?

Comment: maybe finding the compiler option to allow longer lines would be useful...

Comment: i guess you dont know  options are in no way compatable between different compilers. It is useless to be looking at the oracle docs. Dont you have docs for your absoft compiler? call support?

Comment: yeah sorry. I figured there would be specifics, but I thought there would be common options for the most part. I'm not too worried about the longer lines, because I don't really want to reformat my common block. I read that the order in which the variables is arranged is important, and that means I'll have reorder them by hand or with a script I'll need to write.... Thanks

Comment: A common way of breaking up a common block is to declare a massive array and equivalence out different areas

Comment: Thank you @cup. I'll look more into that. Any tips on it?

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer but it is too long too put into a comment.  Say you have something like

```
 parameter (nmax=20)
 integer mint, ifan
 double precision dat, datasp, oat, zrvs
 common /ahu/dat(nmax), datsp(nmax), oat(nmax), zrvs(nmax),
&            mint(nmax), ifan
```

This can be changed to

```
parameter (nmax=20)
parameter (ixfan = 1, ixmint = 2)
double precision shared
integer mint, ifan
double precision dat(nmax), datasp(nmax), oat(nmax), zrvs(nmax)
common /ahu/ shared(nmax * 4), ishared(nmax + 1)
equivalence (shared(1), dat), (shared(nmax+1), datasp)
equivalence (shared(nmax*2+1), oat), (shared(nmax*3+1, zrvs)
equivalence (ishared(ixfan), ifan), (ishared(ixmint), mint)
```

The common block is down to two declarations. You can have as many parameter and   equivalence statements as required and they don't all have to be jammed on one line with lots of continuations.  The rest of the program does not need changing.

Comment: This is terrible advice: why not just use multiple `common` statements for the same common block?

Comment: Oh well, I never knew you could split a common block - learn something every day.